# Preventing BFA in WordPress without using a plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, security, password, server

I use Ubuntu 16.04 Nginx environment and **SSHguard** to prevent Brute Force Attacks (BFAs) on the machine VPS environment itself but I'm not sure how I could prevent BFAs on WordPress without using a plugin.

Unlike Drupal that has an application layer BFA prevention mechanism, WordPress has none.

What is the most minimal way, without a "complex" plugin like WordFence, to prevent BFAs in WordPress admin?

The end state should be that IPs trying to enter more than x times get blocked for at least x time (presumably, the default values).

**Edit: Maybe SSHguard could help with that too?**

Comment: Why do you not want to use a plugin?

Comment: Many popular plugins tend to be snoozy / ticky, embedded with aggressive pro version marketing. Besides I usually prefer to be dependent in less modules as possible.

Comment: If this is how drupal works, no wonder wordpress is used more.... Anyway, what stopping you from implementing your algo by yourself?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge in `iptables`, IPS architecture and regex to create such algorithm. I only know some basic regex (about this `. ? () [] {} ^ $ * | \ \w \s \K`) and I'm very new to PHP so I don't really know where to start with this.

Comment: iptables are not relevant for this, and why do you need any regex?

Comment: You should really try to do this on a server level using something like fail2ban. That's a much more robust solution than doing something in WordPress / PHP.

Comment: I use `sshguard` which is much simpler to implement than `fail2ban`. I wasn't able to find **didactic** f2b documentation aimed for beginners and I don't have enough free time to start creating a guide from different sources.

Comment: Why this question got 3 dislikes?

Comment: Right, I forgot you already use sshguard. That‘s already a very good way to do this. Doing the same thing on the application level will never give you better results/performance. Why do you want to switch? Or are you just interested in how it could work in theory?

Comment: @swissspidy I'll indeed prefer the operating system level regarding the application level, I've edited the question that I'm open to use SSHguard for that cause as well, I just don't know how to configure SSHguard to cover WordPress as well, and not sure I have the right background for that.

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now! Personally I don't really know SSHguard, but [this article](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-wordpress-sshguard) seems to cover setting it up to track WordPress login attempts, which I guess is enough 90% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One ***plugin-free*** layer of protection you could implement is to route your traffic through a site like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/) that has built in brute force protection. The free version is a great layer of protection with paid tiers if you need the added features. I have used this for several of my sites.

I am with you in that I try to use as few plugins as necessary.

*note: felt this would have been better as a comment but *did* not have the necessary reputation.*